# Need help in reading an xml file

Tags: android

I have created an xml folder under res and placed myxml.xml in xml folder.
res/xml/myxml.xml

I want to read the description according to the id number. How can I achieve that?
Please help.

myxml.xml is like this;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Books>
  <Number id ="1">
    <Description>This is childrens book.
    </Description>
  </Number> 
  <Number id = "2">
    <Description>This is about cooking.
   </Description>
</Books>
```

Here is the code I am working with (but doesn't seems to be doing anything)

```
try{
        XmlPullParser xpp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.myxml);
                while(xpp.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            if(xpp.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){ 
              if(xpp.getName().equals("Description")){

                  show1.setText(" " + xpp.getAttributeValue(1));
              }
            }
        xpp.next();
         }
        }
        catch(Throwable t){

        }
```

Comment: Please, **do not** continue posting duplicate questions. I have merged them into this, your original, which you are free to edit to provide additional information.

Answer (score 2):

For what you're trying to achieve here, I'd recommend using [javax.xml.xpath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html). Taken from the example on that page, adapted to your XML file (the XPath here will get the description of Number with id attribute of 2):

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "//Number[@id='2']/Description";

try {
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(activity.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myxml));
    Node node = (Node) xpath.evaluate(expression, inputSource, XPathConstants.NODE);
    String description = node.getTextContent();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("ParseException", e.toString());
}
```

I've updated the example slightly to load the InputSource from a resource input stream. To do this it looks like you'll need to put your xml file in the res/raw folder rather than res/xml (based on this answer: [problem loading and parsing xml from resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864273/problem-loading-and-parsing-xml-from-resources)). I also had to do project > clean to get this to work.

You'll probably also want to handle the parse exception error in a slightly better way!

Comment: I added in the above code  textview.setText(" " + description) but it doesn't displays anything from the xml file. Any ideas? I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the example slightly - hopefully it should work correctly now. Let me know if you have any more issues though.

Answer (score 2):

How will it even work when activity has null in it.. u r doin null.getResources();

Answer (score 1):

you can use this, I am sure that this help you

```
XmlResourceParser pars = res.getXml(R.xml.myxml);
while (pars.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (pars.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
              if(pars.getName().equals("Number")) {
                   int id = pars.getAttributeIntValue(null, "id", 0);
              }
        }
    pars.next();
}
pars.close();
```

in your Xml you have forgotten to put `/` in your Number tag

```
<Number id ="1" />
```

use this link to understand XmlResourceParser, it is evry easy to use
http://www.anddev.org/using_xmlresourceparser_to_parse_custom_compiled_xml-t9313.html

Comment: Thanks George. I tried the above code, it diplays "2" since it is the last item in the xml file. How can I display description in editText with the corresponding id.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working is because you are calling `xrp.getName()` method when your current `eventType` is `XmlPullParser.TEXT`.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#getName%28%29):

> public abstract String getName()
>
> For START_TAG or END_TAG events...If
>   the current event is not START_TAG,
>   END_TAG, or ENTITY_REF, null is
>   returned.

I would create a `Stack<String>` to hold the names of the element I am currently on.  When I get to a start tag, I would push the name to the top, and when i hit an end tag, I would pop the name off the top.  This way, when I am in a text element, I would know the whole xPath of my current location.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in your example the XML appears to missing the closing `</Number>` tag where the id attribute is equal to "2".  Its possible a formatting error such as this may be causing your error.

Comment: That error is not in the code. Is the xmlPullParser the right way to read xml doc.(new to android). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `XPath` for this, the [XMLResourceParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html)-class was meant to do that ([tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/read-xml-resources-in-android-using.html)).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't access APK resources like they're on the path, because they're compiled into your application. If you want to access a resource directly, try this:

```
InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.myxml);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream);
```

You may need use move the XML file into the `res/raw/` folder and use `R.raw.myxml` to access it instead.

Comment: It says "context" cannot be resolved. Can I use "this" instead of context. Thanks

Comment: @artist If you're inside an activity, then yes, `this` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an unexpected situation and your program throws an exception and dies.

Find the printed stack trace and add it to your question.  This will most likely tell you why.  A very common reason is to have uninitialized variables which you then try to invoke a method on giving a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any of your "if" condition is getting satisfies. Return a string that is not empty and see if that gets displayed. If it does, then re-look at your logic for getEventsFromAnXML method.